# Overriding Jquery version

Tags: jquery-ui

I am modifying a website that needs to have a datepicker with yyyy-mm-dd as format.

I am trying JQUERY UI datepicker but the catch is. My site is using

```
jquery-1.2.6.min.js
```

and when I paste:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

as the requisite of date picker from the examples I browsed.

Some of my functions are not working all of a sudden.

Can I somehow use jquery UI without harming the already working website? My task is only to add a datepicker.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to a more recent jquery version? In theory your website should work with the newer version with only minor refactoring.

Comment: Probably best to update the rest of your functions to use the newer jQuery version. They release updates for a reason, namely improvements in memory, performance, compatibility and security. No sense to stay in the past. It might take an hour or two to migrate your functions to the latest stable version, but it will be worth it.

Comment: That is the problem, If I just add these three prerequisites, some just dont work. like Save, after saving it must return to Table Screen, but it somehow shows the JSON code instead

Comment: You can also look into jQuery Migrate, which helps old code to work with newer jQuery releases. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Comment: not to mean to sound negative, but I am really not a web developer, much to say, I cannot comprehend jqueries. Maybe I have to use a javascript datepicker instead of jquery.

Comment: Then, I would try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: may I ask why do some functions cease to work when I upgrade my jquery version?